# How to make my door return to original closed state after a few seconds

Tags: unreal-engine4, blueprint

I made a blueprint which allows me to open a door when a button is pressed, however i need help in making the door return to it's original state after several seconds have passed.

[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsw3D.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Delay node , then connect it to "Reverse node" and connect it to your MatineeActor reference just as you did with Play Node.

that should apply what you want.

I would use timeline node instead so I will be able to place the door and use it within any level anywhere btw.